# MPI - sending parts of image to different processes

Tags: c++, opencv, mpi

I'm writing a program in which process 0 sends parts of image to other processes which transform (long operation) this part and send back to the rank 0. I have a problem with one thing. To reproduce my issue I wrote a simple example. An image with size 512x512px is split on 4 parts (vertical stripes) by process 0. Next other processes save this part on disk. The problem is that each process saves the same part. I discovered that the image is split on parts correctly but problem is probably with sending data. What's wrong in my code?

Run:

```
mpirun -np 5 ./example
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int size, rank;
    MPI_Request send_request, rec_request;
    MPI_Status status;
    ostringstream s;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if (rank == 0) {

        Mat mat = imread("/home/user/original.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        if (!mat.data) exit(-1);

        int idx = 1;
        for (int c = 0; c < 512; c += 128) {
            Mat slice = mat(Rect(c, 0, 128, 512)).clone();
            MPI_Isend(slice.data, 128 * 512 * 3, MPI_BYTE, idx, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request);
            idx++;
        }
    }
    if (rank != 0) {
        Mat test = Mat(512, 128, CV_8UC3);
        MPI_Irecv(test.data, 128 * 512 * 3, MPI_BYTE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rec_request);
        MPI_Wait(&rec_request, &status);

        s << "/home/user/p" << rank << ".jpg";
        imwrite(s.str(), test);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using non-blocking operations, then the proper way to issue multiple of them at the same time is:

```
MPI_Request *send_reqs = new MPI_Request[4];

int idx = 1;
for (int c = 0; c < 512; c += 128) {
    Mat slice = mat(Rect(c, 0, 128, 512)).clone();
    MPI_Isend(slice.data, 128 * 512 * 3, MPI_BYTE, idx, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_reqs[idx-1]);
    idx++;
}

MPI_Waitall(4, send_reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
delete [] send_reqs;
```

Another (and IMHO better) option would be to utilise [`MPI_Scatterv`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Scatterv.3.php) to scatter the original data buffer. Thus you could even save cloning parts of the image matrix.

```
if (rank == 0) {
    Mat mat = imread("/home/user/original.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (!mat.data) exit(-1);

    int *send_counts = new int[size];
    int *displacements = new int[size];

    // The following calculations assume row-major storage
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        send_counts[i] = displacements[i] = 0;
    }
    int idx = 1;
    for (int c = 0; c < 512; c += 128) {
        displacements[idx] = displacements[idx-1] + send_counts[idx-1];
        send_counts[idx] = 128 * 512 * 3;
        idx++;
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(mat.data, send_counts, displacements, MPI_BYTE,
                 NULL, 0, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    delete [] send_counts;
    delete [] displacements;
}
if (1 <= rank && rank <= 4) {
    Mat test = Mat(512, 128, CV_8UC3);
    MPI_Scatterv(NULL, NULL, NULL, MPI_BYTE,
                 test.data, 128 * 512 * 3, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    s << "/home/user/p" << rank << ".jpg";
    imwrite(s.str(), test);
}
```

Note how the arguments to `MPI_Scatterv` are prepared. Since you are scattering to 4 MPI processes only, setting certain elements of `send_counts[]` to zero allows the program to function correctly with more than 5 MPI processes. Also, the root rank in your original code doesn't send to itself, therefore `send_counts[0]` must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not waiting till the send operation completes before the matrix `Mat` is destructed.  Use `MPI_Send` instead of `MPI_Isend`.

If you really want to use non blocking communication,  you have to keep track of all MPI_Request objects and of all `Mat` images until the send is complete.